# Newest Youtube API makes application crash under Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-play-services

My App uses Youtube API to play videos. I've been developing it for more than a year so I've covered different Youtube App versions, from the first ones (uncoupled with Google Services, that were flawless) to the latest versions, that are way more complex, and even silently download and install JARS from google.

The latest **Youtube App 5.17.6** on devices running **Android 4.0.4**. I have the latest Google Play Services lib jar rev.21 (3.2Mb !!) Any attempt to play a video through the API makes **Youtube Application** crash, and then my application crashes as well.

Even though we're talking about an obsolete Android version, there are still quite a lot of devices on ICS.

**Side Info**

- Google Play Services JAR rev.21, also tried rev.10-rev15
- Youtube APP 5.17.6. Older versions work.
- Android 4.0.4 fails, but Android 4.0.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.2 and 4.4.4 work
- Youtube API Demos crash as well, all of them (Fragment / View / CustomControls ...)
- I use YoutubeSupportFragment (but it doesnt' matter, Views also don't work)

The crash is inside Youtube App ("Unfortunately YouTube Has Stopped"), and seems to come from a downloaded ads JAR:

```
D/dalvikvm( 4561): DEX prep '/data/data/com.google.android.youtube/cache/ads1113889427.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 183ms

E/AndroidRuntime( 4561): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-635
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at com.google.android.a.t.a(SourceFile:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.adshield.a.a.<init>(SourceFile:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.adshield.AdShieldCreatorImpl.a(SourceFile:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.adshield.a.e.onTransact(SourceFile:55)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at ehb.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at egs.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at dxw.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at eig.c(SourceFile:142)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at eig.a(SourceFile:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at epu.b(SourceFile:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at epu.b_(SourceFile:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at eih.c(SourceFile:158)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at eih.a(SourceFile:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at epu.b(SourceFile:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at epu.b_(SourceFile:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at eif.c(SourceFile:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at ejg.a(SourceFile:37)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at fgq.j(SourceFile:176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at fhg.e(SourceFile:313)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at fhg.c(SourceFile:25)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at fgy.h(SourceFile:239)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at rl.a(SourceFile:132)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at rl.a(SourceFile:73)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at ri.a(SourceFile:93)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at fxp.a(SourceFile:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at qo.run(SourceFile:105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4561):    ... 27 more
```

Any advice?

I've filed a bug in Google Code at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=youtube%205.17.6&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=6808 ... Please star the issue if you also have this problem.

**EDIT**

Adding the trick @TacBoss proposed for initializing the API, i get the following error when instantiating YouTube API:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: name
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Clients must be created on the UI thread.
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ad.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4075):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

... and if I just execute the **youtubePlayer.cueVideo()** function (the one that triggers the crash) wrapped into the handler, I get the same original error.

Answer (score 1):

Some SDKs has the need to perform all of their actions synchronously, and in order not to block your other threads by synchronizing all their methods they will force a single thread using that SDK, as the most obvious example Android main thread. (I had the "pleasure" of using this sort of SDK, and I also think that the SDK should be responsible for managing the thread changes)

I'm not sure if that is the case here but for now it seems the new SDK has the need to creates a handler on the thread it is called/created on.

I would suggest creating the SDK and **possibly**(depends on any other errors you might encounter) also using it via a single HandlerThread.

Try this:

```
HandlerThread t=new HandlerThread("name");
t.start();
new Handler(t.getLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        start the SDK...
    }
});
```

Update:

OK, So the SDK demands you initialize it on the UI thread... I suggest you start it in the onCreate of your custom application or use this code snippet:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        start the SDK...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your answer, but what you suggest is totally out of my control. Those errors come from a JAR that the Youtube Api downloads and installs itself (!), and it's called deep in the Youtube Play process. As you can see in the stacktrace, there's nothing regarding my app, and I suspect it's even a "backdoor" google service (see android.os.Binder.transact in the stacktrace) :(

Comment: You must initiate the SDK somehow... does the code I've posted works?

Comment: Hey @TacBoss, I upvoted your answer because I learnt about this that for sure is interesting and very useful and I had no clue, but unfortunately, it looks like it doesn't hit the spot inside Youtube Api. As you can see in the stack trace, the crash is already inside a thread, coming from a service, downloaded from whoknowswhere ... you know, google complicated stuff :( If I wrap the SDK init into the handler, I get an error as you see in the EDIT, and if I wrap just the play command, nothing changes. thanks for the advanced tip, though!

Comment: Annoying... they avtually want you to initiate the sdk on the ui thread... try from an oncreate of your custom application

Comment: nah I just give up,it's terribly convoluted, because the SDK itself is loaded in a fragment, so forget onCreate, you need to instantiate the fragment, wait until it becomes created and alive, initialize it ... besides as I point out, it's not even my app the one that crashes, but a second app (Youtube.apk) spawned by Youtube SDK that in turn starts a service (ads1113889427.jar) ... And all this after including a 4mb library, installing a 10mb application and 15mb "Google Play Services". I remember not that long ago when google was "normal" and all it took was a few hundred kb jar.